# How do I import a list of songs from the Billboard website to a Google Sheet?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have seen online that you can pull data from websites using the [`IMPORTHTML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en) function in Google Sheets. However, you can only import tables and lists. I have tried both of these on the Billboard top 100 chart list but because they are separated into divs, not lists nor tables, I cannot seem to get it to work.

How do I do it using the `IMPORTHTML` function? If this is not possible, how do I use things like the Genius website API with the Google Sheets API to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in **A1** cell:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100", 
 "//div[@class='chart-list-item__artist']")
```

paste in **B1** cell:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100", 
 "//span[@class='chart-list-item__title-text']")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Amazing thank you very much! I forgot to mention in my post that I also need the lyrics of each song next to it. Is there a way to do this using the same method by using such charts as the genius top charts https://genius.com/#top-songs ? It has lyrics but you have to click on each song individually to get them

Comment: I've accepted it - any idea on how to get the lyrics for each song in the list in the rightmost column on google spreadsheets?

Comment: while it's not impossible it would be suicide mission coz code is (on purpose) very scattered - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjWbx.png - so for every line of lyrics you would need 1 formula and soon you would hit importrange limit of google sheets. you will need to find a more friendly site